# Inner Join + Where em MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, where

Como utilizar `INNER JOIN` com `WHERE`?

Estou fazendo um `INNER JOIN` com 3 tabelas. 
Preciso de um `WHERE` para retornar apenas um registro. Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT `*` FROM (`tabela1`) 
INNER JOIN `tabela2` ON `tabela1`.`id` = `tabela2`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `tabela3` ON `tabela2`.`id` = `tabela3`.`id` 
WHERE `tabela1`.`id` = 12;
```

Só que o MySQL me retorna esse erro:

> Column 'id_militar' in where clause is ambiguous

Quero receber apenas um registro no `INNER JOIN`, não todos da tabela. Como faço?

Comment: Você realmente colocou `nome_tabela.id_militar` no where? Pois esse erro apresentado quer dizer que existe `id_militar` em mais de uma dentre as tabelas selecionadas e ele não sabe qual você está comparando.

Comment: Você está especificando de qual tabela é o campo "id_militar" ? Porque parece que ele existe em mais de uma tabela e você não está especificando de qual delas que é.

Comment: Exatamente o que voces falaram, eu estava fazendo duas comparaçoes com o mesmo valor (tabela.id). Obrigado, problemas resolvido